# Detect signs on roads

Tags: c, image, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have a video which has got turn left,turn right etc marks on the roads.
I have to detect those signs.I am going ahead with template matching in which I am matching the edge detected outputs,But I am not getting satisfactory results,Is there any other way to detect it? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a solution that is not too complicated but more robust than template matching, I suggest you'd go for Hough voting on SIFT descriptors. This method is provides some degree of robustness to various problems, including partial occlusion of the sign, illumination variations and deformations of the sign. In particular, the method is completely invariant to rotation and uniform scaling of the template object.

The basic idea of the algorithm is as follows:

a) extract SIFT features from the template and query images.

b) set an arbitrary reference point in the template image and calculate, for each keypoint in the template image, the vector from the keypoint to the reference point.

c) match keypoints from the template image to the query image.

d) cast a vote for each matched keypoint for all object locations in the query image that this keypoint agrees with. You do that using the vectors calculated in step (b) and the location, scale and orientation of the matched keypoints in the query image.

e) If the object is indeed located in the image, the votes map should have a strong local maximum at it's location.

f) Optionally, you can verify the detection by using template matching.

You can read more about that method on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform#Cluster_identification_by_Hough_transform_voting) or in the original paper (by D. Lowe) [here](http://www.cis.rit.edu/~cnspci/references/dip/feature_extraction/lowe2001.pdf).

Comment: could you be more precise for your point D ? I am using the OpenCV implemenation but there isn't anything like that, only RANSAC with Homography. I would like to use Hough voting, but I don't clearly get the "for all object locations in the query image that this keypoint agrees with" given only 1 match which are all the locations that keypoints agrees ?

Comment: I'll explain what casting a vote for a keypoint means: You create an image of the same dimension as your query image, initialized to all zeros. This is the votes map. Now, for each matched keypoint you add some positive value to the vote map, at the keypoint's image coordinates. After adding up the votes for all keypoints, you have your vote map ready, and now look for strong maxima in it. Note that you don't add a value to just one pixel at the vote map around the keypoint, but you add a 2D Gaussian centered at its' coordinates, in order to account for the location uncertainty of the keypoint

Answer (score 0):

Using SIFT or SURF. You can get the invariable descriptor with  training you can determine if the vector that represent the road marks (turn left, right or stop) match with the new in the video.

Answer (score 0):

You might try extracting features and training a classifier (linear discriminant, neural network, naive Bayes, etc.).  There are many candidate features you might try, but I'd think that you wouldn't need anything too complicated, even if the edge detection is poor, assuming that isolation of the sign is good.  Some features to consider are: horizontal and vertical projections (row and column totals) and simple statistics of edge pixels (mean, standard deviation, skewness, etc.  For more feature ideas, see any of these books:

"Shape Classification and Analysis: Theory and Practice", by Costa and Cesar

"Algorithms for Image Processing and Computer Vision", by J. R. Parker

"Digital Image Processing", by Gonzalez and Woods

Comment: It's difficult to come up with a working algorithm based on this answer without an extensive amount of additional research (which features to choose? which classifier to choose? how well would a concrete combination of feature and classifier would do together? how much positive and negative examples are needed to train the classifier? how to deal with variable illumination, pose, clutter, occlusions, noise, blur, etc?).